# Phoenix Elixir html_response test left-hand value and right-hand value not same?

Tags: unit-testing, controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple controller test for html response. Why does `assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "New User"` produce this:

[image]

While it only should test for 200 OK response? (it is 200, and removing the =~ "New User" works though).

Comment: Please delete the screenshot and copy paste the output for future reference.

Comment: Check the docs here https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#html_response/2

Answer (score 4):

I think your error is due to a typo. Your looking for "New User" in the response but I could only find "New user" in your screenshot (check the case)

If you want to do insensitive-case string comparison, you can do :

`assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ ~r/New User/i`

PS: next time don't upload a screenshot, copy-paste the output. It would have taken less time to find the issue